# How to render the html page after getting response from the function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to call a function on my body load. I want to render my html page after getting the response from the function. For example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function welcome(){
            alert("Welcome");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="welcome()">
    <p>hai</p>
</body>
```

I want the hai to be displayed after pressing ok in the alert box. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Welcome");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>hai</p>
</body>
```

This would alert before the body is loaded, then when you clicked 'ok' it would load the body.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body onload="render()">
<script>
var content = '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
function render() {
    var answer = confirm('Do you want to render the page?');
    if (answer) {
        document.body.innerHTML = content;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[And a live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/daWbb/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function welcome(){
        alert("Welcome");
    }
    welcome();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>hai</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
 <body onload="welcome()">
  <p id='hi'></p>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function welcome(){
  alert("Welcome");
  document.getElementById('hi').innerHTML='hi';
 }
 </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the body to make contents not visible and remove it after the function is called..

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function welcome(){
            alert("Welcome");
            document.body.className = '';
        }
      </script>
      <style type="text/css">
         .invisible{visibility:hidden;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="welcome()" class="invisible">
        <p>hai</p>
    </body>
</html>
```